# Как расшифровать свое собственное сообщение?

Tags: javascript, node.js, шифрование

На данный момент каждое сообщение зашифровывается с помощью **[этого](https://github.com/WhisperSystems/libsignal-protocol-javascript)**. Планирую это зашифрованное сообщение хранить в БД. Сейчас это зашифрованное сообщение может расшифровать лишь получатель, т.е. отправитель не может расшифровать свое сообщение, взяв его из БД. Поэтому я не могу хранить историю сообщений. Т.е. если пользователь выйдет из "чата", то при следующем входе он не увидит свои собственные сообщения.

И вот вопрос: можно ли расшифровать свое собственное сообщение? Или же нужно хранить свои сообщения на каком-то локальном хранилище?

Comment: можно отправить в БД сообщение 2 раза. зашифрованное публичными ключами получателя и отправителя. тогда для того что бы показать собственные сообщения из БД надо будет взять то, что шифровалось своим ключем.

Comment: в этом протоколе используется сеансовый ключ. этот ключ генерируется случайным образом. после закрытия соединения ключ пропадает. ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от того на сколько вы хотите обезопасить сохраненные сообщения?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman То есть для хранения истории сообщений(как своих, так и чужих), нужно будет их хранить на устройстве пользователя? И какой тогда смысл в шифровании...

Comment: @AynurSibagatullin данная библиотека защищает сообщения при передачи по открытому каналу. Как организовать хранение - зависит от задачи которую вы хотите решить.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Спасибо.

Comment: @Mike, а зачем отправленное хранить? Можно же его всегда ещё раз зашифровать при необходимости? Т. е. можно хранить только одно из двух, а именно то, которое самому потом можно расшифровать.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я так понял что в одной БД все сообщения и оправляемые и получаемые. А пользователи обращаются к ним по мере необходимости. Исходя из этого и решил, что придется хранить два раза шифрованные разными ключами

Comment: @Mike, это как-то странно...